# WPF Combobox - Displaying Count in Label

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've got a simple WPF ComboBox, displaying Orders/Positions on the Financial Markets.

```
<ComboBox Name="TradeDropDown" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveOrders}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="OrderLabel"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOrder, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

[image: screenshot of dropdown]

I need to see at a glance how many items are in the list.  I've added a TextBlock above with summary information.

I don't like it, and would prefer to have the items in the dropdown listed like:

```
(1/2) Working Short 425K
(2/2) Filled Long 979K
```

etc - and have the 1/2 numbers correctly update as items are added and removed from the list.

The Items are stored in a BindingList.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to do this?

Add another property to the class where the `OrderLabel` property is defined that returns a string like "(1/2) Working Short 425K" and set the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the `ComboBox` to the name of this property.

Make sure that the class implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

You then set the new property to a new value and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever you want to update the label in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: That would require orders to know about each other. If you add an object to a list the object has no clue it's in a list, what position it's in in the list or how many other items are in a list. When I said (1/2) I mean "item one of two".